# Animating transition between fragments crashes

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction, objectanimator

I am trying to animate a transition between two fragments by fading the current to the left and fading in the new one from the right. The app crashes on runtime.

**minSdkVersion:** 16
**targetSdkVersion:** 23
**emulator running on api version 23**

**Activity code**

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_right, R.animator.exit_to_left);
    transaction.replace(R.id.listFragmentContainer, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

**res/animator/enter_from_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<ObjectAnimator
    android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

**res/animator/exit_to_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<ObjectAnimator
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

**LogCat**

```
02-17 12:00:25.028 16696-16696/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.eivind.ticktick, PID: 16696
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: ObjectAnimator
```

Comment: change ObjectAnimator  to objectAnimator

Comment: Now it works, but not how I intedended.. Thank you for solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just miss writing [objectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) element

change ObjectAnimator to objectAnimator  to be like this

**res/animator/enter_from_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<objectAnimator
    android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

**res/animator/exit_to_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<objectAnimator
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```